# Can't get user access token facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

I manage a comapny's facebook fanpage (with a lot of posts and comments). To collect posts and comments from my company fanpage, I created an app and an extended page access token and did data collection successfully. After about an hour through data collection, I got an error and the process was halted. I suspect I might have used a temporary page access token, instead of the extended page access token, for the data collection.

Next day, I deleted the old app and created a new app to get "user access token" with manage_page permission and "page access token". However, a new user access token/page access token is never issued again. I clicked on the submitt button, but no access token is generated anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should add the exact process/code how you generate an extended page token

Comment: Why did you delete the existing app in the first place? That’s not the way to handle things. And what _specific_ error did you get? It makes little sense to discuss this as long as you are only _assuming_ token expiry was the reason.